# Sequelize ORM relations vs foreign keys

Tags: database-design, orm, model, foreign-keys, sequelize.js

I'm about to start new solo project and use Sequelize ORM which I've used in another projects with my colleagues. I've searched a little more SQ docs and figured out that SQ support both model relations and classic foreign keys. I am foreign keys fan but model relations also is powerful way to organize database models and potentialy has more flexibility then foreign keys (IMHO).

**So can somebody give an advice of what is better to use in different cases or database architectures?**

My new project must not have some polymorphic relations and other strange and difficult structures (at least I hope so) but it will be long-time product with multiple functions and abilities so it have to be flexible enough. Also I don't plan to use anything but project ORM to modify database (mariadb).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Model relations do not offer more power or flexibility than foreign keys: they're the framework's way of expressing those same relationships. `A.belongsTo(B)`, for example, is a "Sequelizey" way of saying that an A record has a foreign key to a B record, which is how the dependency is established in the database schema (if you do establish a hard dependency, which Sequelize allows you to skip).

When it comes to making relationships explicit, it's important to remember that database-level constraints are law, and the only way to really ensure that your data stays correct. Anything else -- including the definition of `hasOne` or `belongsTo` in your models -- is *advice* which *may* be respected *sometimes* and so cannot guarantee integrity.  Use proper foreign key constraints.